# Postman generate crypto hash gives error: TypeError: crypto.createHash is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, postman, sha256, cryptojs

I am trying to create a Postman pre-requisite script by converting the below TS code.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

const createTestingUserHash = (emailAddress: string, timestamp: string, salt: string) =>
  crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(`testinguserhash::${emailAddress}::${timestamp}::${salt}`)
    .digest('base64');

export const getLoginLink = async (email: string): Promise<string | undefined> => 
{

  const currentTimeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
  const testingHash = createTestingUserHash(email, currentTimeStamp, testingUserSalt);
  .
  .
  .
```

My Postman script:

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');

const signToken = () => {
    const timestamp = "2022-06-23T14:51:34.694Z";
    const salt = "salt_value";
    const email = "testing@test.io";

    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(`testinguserhash::${emailAddress}::${timestamp}::${salt}`).digest("base64");
    return (hash);
}

const signedToken = signToken();
console.log(`successfully generated hash : ${signedToken}`)
```

I also tried `var hash = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', "secret").update("Message").digest('base64');` but Postman throws a similar error.

Can someone help me build this script?

Comment: Why don't you log `crypto` and see what's inside it?

Comment: why would `crypto` and `crypto-js` be the same thing? also `the below JS code` is NOT JS code - it may be typescript though

Comment: [this is the nodejs crypto documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) ... this is [crypto-js](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) (I think) ... two very different API's

Comment: if you want the same crypto API in both nodejs and the browser ... search for subtleCrypto - then the code can be identical (though, you'd have to rewrite both)

Comment: @Bravo yes, it was a typo, it is TS. I am not allowed to change the TS code here. I just want a similar version of Postman script which I understand is based on NodeJS

Comment: well, postman doesn't have access to nodejs crypto library - I can show you how to use subtle crypto (I assume postman has access to that browser built-in crypto?)

Comment: although ... `crypto.SHA256(\`testinguserhash::${emailAddress}::${timestamp}::${salt}\`).toString(crypto.enc.Base64);` should probably work with crypto-js - once you chane `const email = "testing@test.io";` to `const emailAddress = "testing@test.io";`

Comment: ^ This works, hash is generated. Thanks @Bravo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crypto-js has a completely different but [well documented](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) interface compared to node.js [crypto library](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

The equivalent crypto-js code is

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');

const signToken = () => {
    const timestamp = "2022-06-23T14:51:34.694Z";
    const salt = "salt_value";
    const emailAddress = "testing@test.io";

    return crypto.SHA256(`testinguserhash::${emailAddress}::${timestamp}::${salt}`).toString(crypto.enc.Base64);
}

const signedToken = signToken();
console.log(`successfully generated hash : ${signedToken}`)
```